# iPhone app server communication XML or JSON?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios4

Which method is easier and more efficient? XML or Json
Where can I find a tutorial and code samples for each?

Comment: what kind of data are you working with?

Comment: I have a template that looks like this web page and need to fill in the data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently learned how to use JSON on the iPhone and it was very easy.

Here's a framework:

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

General JSON info can be found here:

http://www.json.org/

Comment: does iphone sdk have native XML capabilities?

Comment: There's also the XML PList format, which is even easier to parse.